# Oracle Entity Framework passing parameter to command text

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, oracle10g

i have a table test

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
  ID    NUMBER,
  NAME  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
)


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON test
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT test_sequence.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
END;

ALTER TABLE TEST ADD (
  PRIMARY KEY
 (ID)
```

Now I want to insert from a page with values from textbox.

The code is given below

```
protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string name = Convert.ToString(ASPxTextBox1.Text);
        int retVal = 0;
        string providerName = "Oracle.DataAccess.Client";
        string constr =
               @"User Id=scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=orcl;enlist=true";

        // Get the provider factory.
        DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);

        try
        {

            using (scope txn = new scope())
            {
                using (DbConnection conn1 = factory.CreateConnection())
                {
                    conn1.ConnectionString = constr;
                    conn1.Open();

                    // Create a command to execute the sql statement.
                    DbCommand cmd1 = factory.CreateCommand();
                    cmd1.Connection = conn1;
                    cmd1.CommandText = @"insert into test ( [NAME] ) values (:name)";
                    //OracleParameter Nameprm = cmd1.Parameters.Add("name" , OracleDbType.Varchar2, 10 );
                    //Nameprm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    //Nameprm.Value = ASPxTextBox1;
                    var name = Convert.ToString(ASPxTextBox1);
                    var parameter = factory.CreateParameter();
                    parameter.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
                    parameter.ParameterName = "@name";
                    parameter.Value = name;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                    retVal = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //Console.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by cmd1: {0}", retVal);

                    // Close the connection and dispose the command object.
                    conn1.Close();
                    conn1.Dispose();
                    cmd1.Dispose();

                }

                txn.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

But i am always getting ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword. but if i give values directly then its inserting data. I am trying to solve it in many ways still no luck. Your help will be very much appreciated as i am stuck here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@competent_tech 's answer looks good, as an additional thought:

In my last job-but-one we used a massive Oracle database for all our persistence, and I had no end of grief with this sort of problem.  Most of them were solved when I stopped using the built-in ADO.Net drivers and used the Oracle provided drivers (as recommended by Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7.aspx)).

You can get the Oracle Data Provider for .Net (ODP.Net) for your version of Oracle [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html).

If you're already using the ODP.Net my sincere apologies, it's a little hard to tell from the code snippet :)

If the name isn't the problem, then it may be with the parameter type (OracleDBType.VarChar2, although this should be inferred for you by DbType) or the parameter direction (ParameterDirection.InputOnly parameter?)

I hope that might help :)

Comment: karl Lynch sir thanks for sharing your experience . From the beginning of my project i always tried to use odp.net(odac).below is my libraries using System;

Comment: using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

Comment: Yes i tried with or without parameter.direction . in both case it worked. And finally i got the problem . its in the line var name = Convert.ToString(ASPxTextBox1); that should be ar name = Convert.ToString(ASPxTextBox1.text);. Lollz my mind is very creepy i guess. Need to see before i press tab. Anyway thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your parameter name is correct.

Try changing:

```
parameter.ParameterName = "@name";
```

to

```
parameter.ParameterName = "name";
```

Comment: `code` parameter.ParameterName = "@name"; and `code` parameter.ParameterName = "name"; both works. the problem is in the line var name = Convert.ToString(ASPxTextBox1); that should be var name = Convert.ToString(ASPxTextBox1.text). and now it works. Thanks for your kind co-operation. i would like to hear from you again in future.